# Unix sed command - extract text between 2 slashes

Tags: unix, sed

apologies for a basic question using sed, I have been trying to work it out but my brain fails me...

I am trying to extract the text between two slashes within some unix shell.

I would like to extract the text between the 3rd and 4th slash (DEV). I have been trying to contruct the the following but without success..

```
echo "/share/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF" |
sed 's|\(.3\)/.4|\1|'
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks M

Answer (score 2):

It should be an easy task with `awk`, try following. Simply setting field separator to `/` and printing 4th field as per output required.

```
echo "/share/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF" | awk -F'/' '{print $4}'
```

With `sed` you can try following:

```
echo "/share/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF" | 
sed -E 's/^\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/([^/]*)\/.*/\1/'
```

OR

```
sed -E 's_^/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]*)/.*_\1_' Input_file
```

Comment: you could use `_` as a pattern deliminator to avoid the need to escape all those `/` like so: `sed -E 's_^/[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]*)/.*_\1_'`

Comment: @mattb, sure added it there along with existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sh
path="/share/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF"
IFS='/' read -ra arr <<< "$path"
echo ${arr[3]}
```

**Results**: `DEV`.

Same results with `path="/dir with space/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF"`.

Comment: Nice but fails on `path="/dir with space/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF"`.

Answer (score 1):

`cut -d/ -f4`

`-d` for the delimiter, `-f4` for the 4th item (the 1st is presumed to be empty)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's#^(([^/]*)/){4}.*#\2#p' file
```

Extract the fourth field from a record delimited by `/`'s.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Cut command:**

```
echo "/share/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF" |cut -d/ -f4
```

Where,

> -d : delimiter
> -f : field no.

**Using Awk command:**

```
echo "/share/test/DEV/2021-05-21/out/9988776_948016287_1.PDF" |awk -F/ '{print $4}'
```

> -F : Field Separator